# Querystring with url-encoded ampersand prematurely decoded within Request.Url

Tags: .net, asp.net, query-string, sitecore, url-encoding

Given url `/Page.aspx?a=b&title=apples+%26+pears`, `Request.Url` property returns `/Page.aspx?a=b&title=apples+&+pears`

Note that the url-encoded ampersand in the second key-value pair has been automatically decoded.
Other url-encoded reserved characters aren't being automatically decoded.

Is this behaviour correct?

**EDIT:** The issue is that Request.Url property is automatically decoding the encoded ampersand when I don't expect it to.

**ANSWER:** `string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Sitecore.Context.Request.RawUrl)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Url` property of the `Request` gets decoded in an internal method called  `CollapsePercentUFromStringInternal`.

You can see this in the reflector. This I assumed is the **default behaviour** anyway.

**Update**

You can use RawUrl property to get hold of the un-decoded URL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This to me seems counter-intuitive. Querystring **values** should not be auto-decoded.

Comment: @Arnold There is RawUrl property that you can use if you need to and is not decoded.

Comment: RawUrl is relative, but it led me to the right solution. I've marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

**Reserved characters**
URLs use some characters for special use in defining their syntax. When these characters are not used in their special role inside a URL, they need to be encoded.

```
 
 Dollar          ("$")
 Ampersand       ("&")
 Plus            ("+")
 Comma           (",")
 Forward slash   ("/")
 Colon           (":")
 Semi-colon      (";")
 Equals          ("=")
 Question mark   ("?")
 'At' symbol     ("@")
```

**UnSafe charracters**

Some characters present the possibility of being misunderstood within URLs for various reasons. These characters should also always be encoded.

> Percent character ("%")
>
> 'Pound' character ("#")
>
> Less Than' symbol ("<")
> 'Greater Than' symbol  (">")
> Space

So the behaviour of URL encoding is correct..

Comment: The querystring values *are* being encoded. The issue is that Request.Url property is automatically decoding the encoded ampersand when I don't expect it to.