# IIS treats double-encoded forward slashes in URLs differently on the first request than it does on subsequent requests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, httpmodule

Recently my team was asked to implement an HttpModule for an ASP.NET MVC application that handled double-encoded URLs on IIS 7 and .NET 3.5.  Here's the crux of the problem:

We sometimes get URLs that have double-encoded forward slashes that look like so:

```
http://www.example.com/%252fbar%5cbaz/foo
```

There are other formats that we have to handle as well, but they all have something in common, they have a double-encoded forward slash.

To fix this, we wrote an HttpModule that only acts when a URL has a double encoded forward slash, and we redirect it to a sane URL.  The details aren't important, but there are two bits that are:

1. We can't control the fact that these URLs have double-encoded forward slashes
2. And we have not ugpraded to .NET 4.0 yet, nor is it on the immediate horizon.

Here's the problem:

The first request after IIS starts up shows a different URL than the second request does.

If we used the URL from the above example, the first request to IIS would look like:

`http://www.example.com/bar/baz/foo`

and the second request would look like:

`http://www.example.com/%252fbar%5cbaz/foo`

This was done by inspecting the `Application.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` property while debugging.

Here's the smallest code example that should reproduce the problem (create a new MVC application, and register the following HttpModule):

```
public class ForwardSlashHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    internal IHttpApplication Application { get; set; }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Application = null;
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        Initialize(new HttpApplicationAdapter(context));
    }
    
    internal void Initialize(IHttpApplication context)
    {
        Application = context;
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }
    
    internal void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = Application.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; //<-- Problem point
        //Do stuff with Url here.
    }
}
```

Then, call the same URL on localhost:

```
http://www.example.com/%252fbar%5c/foo
```

> NB: Make sure to insert a `Debugger.Launch()` call before the line in `context_BeginRequest` so that you'll be able to see it the first time IIS launches

When you execute the first request, you should see:

`http://example.com/bar/foo`

on subsequent requests, you should see:

`http://example.com//bar/foo`.

My question is: Is this a bug in IIS?  Why does it provide different URLs when calling `Application.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` the first time, but not for any subsequent request?

Also: It doesn't matter whether the first request is for a double encoded URL or not, the second request will always be handled appropriately by IIS (or at least, as appropriate as handling double-encoded forward slashes can be). It's that very first request that is the problem.

#### Update

I tried a few different properties to see if one had different values on the first request:

First Request

```
string u = Application.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
"http://example.com/foo/baz/bar/"
string x = Application.Request.Url.OriginalString;
"http://example.com:80/foo/baz/bar"
string y = Application.Request.RawUrl;
"/%2ffo/baz/bar"
bool z = Application.Request.Url.IsWellFormedOriginalString();
true
```

The only interesting thing is that the `Application.Request.RawUrl` emits a single-encoded Forward slash (`%2f`), and translates the encoded backslash (`%5c`) to a forwardslash (although everything else does that as well).

The `RawUrl` is still partially encoded on the first request.

Second Request

```
string u = Application.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
"http://example.com//foo/baz/bar"
string x = Application.Request.Url.OriginalString;
"http://example.com:80/%2ffoo/baz/bar"
string y = Application.Request.RawUrl;
"/%2ffoo/baz/bar"
bool z = Application.Request.Url.IsWellFormedOriginalString();
false
```

Interesting points from the second request:

- `IsWellFormedOriginalString()` is `false`. On the first request it was `true`.
- The RawUrl is the same (potentially helpful).
- The `AbsoluteUri` is different. On the second request, it has two forward slashes.

#### Update

```
Application.Request.ServerVariables["URL"] = /quotes/gc/v12/CMX
Application.Request.ServerVariables["CACHE_URL"] = http://example.com:80/%2ffoo/baz/bar
```

Open Questions

- This seems like a bug in either IIS or .NET. Is it?
- This only matters for the *very first* request made by an application after an `iisreset`
- Besides using RawUrl (as we'd have to worry about a lot of other problems if we parsed the Raw Url instead of using the 'safe' URL provided by .NET), what other methods are there for us to handle this?

Keep in mind, the physical impact of this problem is low: For it to be an actual problem, the first request to the web server from a client would have to be for the above specific URL, and the chances of that happening are relatively low.

Answer (score 2):

Request.Url can be decoded already - I wouldn't trust it for what you are doing.

See the internal details at:
[Querystring with url-encoded ampersand prematurely decoded within Request.Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986736/querystring-with-url-encoded-ampersand-prematurely-decoded-within-request-url)

The solution is to access the values directly via Request.RawUrl.

I realize your prob is with the path, but it seems the same thing is going on. Try the RawUrl - see if it works for you instead.

Comment: ok, how about checking the header CACHE_URL? If this is decoded, then its IIS OR browser behavior by the time you get it.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757806/get-the-exact-url-the-user-typed-into-the-browser for more info

Comment: If its not decoded and HTTP_URL is, then its IIS doing the encoding. If both are unencoded, then likely all asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't an answer, but possibly a step in the right direction.  I haven't had time to create a test harness to prove anything.

I followed `this.PrivateAbsolutePath` through Reflector and it goes on and on.  There is a lot of string manipulation when it's accessed.

```
public string AbsolutePath
{
    get
    {
        if (this.IsNotAbsoluteUri)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("net_uri_NotAbsolute"));
        }
        string privateAbsolutePath = this.PrivateAbsolutePath; //HERE
        if (this.IsDosPath && (privateAbsolutePath[0] == '/'))
        {
            privateAbsolutePath = privateAbsolutePath.Substring(1); 
        }
        return privateAbsolutePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesnt this just say if the path starts with a /, chop it off? theres no decoding done here.

Comment: @RandomEngy That's the crux of my question too: Why is something different on the first request than on the second request. I'm going to look at the other answer and the other comments and try what's listed there; but that's the part that bothers me, that the behavior changes from the first request to the second. It doesn't seem like it should unless IIS is handling it the first time, and pushing it on to .NET for each subsequent request (because maybe .NET is still spinning up for the first request?)

Comment: ASP.NET always handles everything, even the first request. My guess is that some initialization code is directly or indirectly causing this behavior.

Comment: It's not, it's executed every time, but you are looking at one property of an entire class dependent and a ton of things under the hood that might not be working the same every time.  Reflect on this.PrivateAbsolutePath and you will know what I mean.